# UIImagepickerController changes capturing frame size with a double tap

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have customized UIImagePickerController for capturing Video frames on my own style. I created an UIImagePickerController like as below.

```
self.iPicker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.iPicker.delegate = self;
self.iPicker.sourceType = sourceType;

self.iPicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
self.iPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
self.iPicker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
self.iPicker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
self.iPicker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:
                           UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
self.iPicker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
self.iPicker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
```

But when I double tap on the capturing screen before clicking a record button, it changes capturing frame size as a retina size. If I do it again, it returns back to original size.
I don't want such a behavior in my picker controller. I want to change the picker size when a user choose a video quality from the setting menu.

As everybody know, there are 6 quality types with those video capturing size for a UIImagePickerController object. They are like as the followings.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIImagePickerControllerQualityType) {
    UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh = 0,       // highest quality
    UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium = 1,     // medium quality, suitable for transmission via Wi-Fi 
    UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeLow = 2,         // lowest quality, suitable for tranmission via cellular network
    UIImagePickerControllerQualityType640x480 = 3,    // VGA quality
    UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame1280x720 = 4,
    UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame960x540 = 5
};
```

Please help me to fix the problem of automatic changing behavior.